# How can I find artifact upload panel in NEXUS 3.0 version?

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to find below panel in NEXUS 3.0 version to upload maven repository.

[image]

Many document say I can find clicking repository.

But In these two pictures, I can not find this panel.

where is this panel??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some document.

It says that about this function, in 3.x, UI not support.

So I degraged to 2.x